# Signal reach in matrix algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I found an algorithm problem and I've been thinking a possible solution to it but I just can think about the "intuitive" one, let's see if someone can lend me a hand.

The problem is the following, we have a `n*m matrix` in which we have empty spaces represented by `.` and walls represented by `%`. We can place a "router" (represented by `R`) in any place `(i,j)` inside the matrix with a range of `n` steps/cells . Consider that a step can only be up/down/left/right.
Which is the most efficient way to check the range of the router?

Example (n=4)

```
. . . . . . . . . .
. . % % . . . . . .
. . % . . . % . . .
. . . . R . % . . .
. . % . . . % . . .
. . % . . . . . . .
```

Soltion (`#` marks signal reach)

```
. . . # # # . . . .
. . % % # # # . . .
. # % # # # % . . .
# # # # R # % . . .
. # % # # # % . . .
. . % # # # # . . .
```

I've been investigating and found the Flood Fill algorithm, I guess I could use it with an extra parameter to check the steps I've already used recursively. Do any of you know any algorithm that could more efficient?

If you'd like to write some code feel free to use any language you want. Thank you beforehand guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use BFS. You basically use a queue to visit the nodes layer by layer.

Using BFS it will visit the cells like this (consider R as (0,0)):

```
t = 0 - Queue = {(0,0)}
For each element in query, visit north, east, west, south if not 
visited and not wall
For (0, 0) -> Visit (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)
. . . . . . . . . .
. . % % . . . . . .
. . % . . . % . . .
. . . . R . % . . .
. . % . . . % . . .
. . % . . . . . . .

t = 1 Queue = {(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)}
For each element in query, visit north, east, west, south if not visited and not wall
For (1, 0) -> Visit (2, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1)
For (0, 1) -> Visit  (0, 2), (-1, 1)
For (-1, 0) -> Visit (-1, 0), (-2, 0)
For (0, -1) -> Visit (-1, -1), (0, -2)

. . . . . . . . . .
. . % % . . . . . .
. . % . # . % . . .
. . . # R # % . . .
. . % . # . % . . .
. . % . . . . . . .

t = 2 and so on
. . . . . . . . . .
. . % % # . . . . .
. . % # # # % . . .
. . # # R # % . . .
. . % # # # % . . .
. . % . # . . . . .


t = 3
. . . . # . . . . .
. . % % # # . . . .
. . % # # # % . . .
. # # # R # % . . .
. . % # # # % . . .
. . % # # # . . . .
```

Comment: Nice aproach! I'll try to implement it.